# How to write a SPSS syntax that goes through all cases and copy value of one case to another based on value of another variable?

Tags: spss

I want to write a SPSS syntax to create a variable called "New" that is derived based on this logic:

- If ID2 = 1 and SF_ID = 1 and Q1 = 1, then New = 1 for all cases with the same ID1.
- If else, New = 0.

Note: For each ID1, there are 2 ID2 (ID2 = 1 and ID2 = 2).

I tried using compute:

```
Compute New = 0.
if (ID2 = 1 and SF_ID = 1 and Q1 = 1) New = 1. 
execute.
```

But I don't know how to write a syntax that duplicate the value of New = 1 for cases where  SF_ID = 1 and Q1 = 1 to the other case with the same ID1.

Please see the following table for desired outcome:

| ID1 | ID2 | SF_ID | Q1 | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate` will do the trick:

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables overwritevars=yes
     /break=ID1 /new=max(new).
```

After running this all values of `new` for each ID1 will turn to 1 if any of them was 1 before.